# Galera cluster Replikation

Tags: galera

I built a galera cluster out of three Pi. The users are automatically copied to all servers. The databasename, tablename, columnname too. But they are always empty. So a select on a table only returns entries on the created server. I am absolutely new to the cluster area. Thank you if someone can help LG

Comment: How did you build your 9.42 cluster?  In particular, how did you build the 2nd and 3rd? 
 Did you turn on, then off, "bootstrap"?  What are the "wsrep%" settings?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I assume that you are using mariadb.
Make sure there is Primary Component in the cluster, you may check in using Status variable [wsrep_cluster_status](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/galera-cluster-status-variables/#wsrep_cluster_status)

Also, please always check the server log, if something goes wrong. **Log is your friend.**